# CORS issue with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Needing a websocket with my website, I wanted to use [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io).

However, I am experiencing a CORS issue:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:2021/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NlbFGS2' from origin 'http://localhost:63341' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polling-xhr.js:202 

GET http://localhost:2021/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NlbFGS2 net::ERR_FAILED
```

So I found this code on the socket.io site that I tried but I still have the same problem...

```js
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:63341/"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})
```

And here is the code on the client side:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@4.1.2/dist/socket.io.msgpack.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let socket = io('http://localhost:2021')
</script>
```

Comment: `localhost:63341` is not the same as `localhost:2021`

Comment: @Joe your answer reminded me of this tortilla picture lmao https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=10+not+8+tortiaas&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Ft4y7p6waj9u41.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these steps on your `backend` server:**

1. Run `npm install cors`
2. Add this code after creating `app`:

   ```
   app.use(cors({
       origin: "http://localhost:63341"
   }))
   ```
3. Restart your server and check if it works or not.
4. If it still doesn't work, then change your `line 3` with this:

   ```
   const io = require("socket.io")(http); // no cors configuration.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to just allow anything to connect... Don't do this in production though.

```
export const io = new Server(http, {
  cors: { origin: "*" },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// at server side
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// at client side
  this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000', {
      withCredentials: true
    });
```

replace http://localhost:4200 with your url

Answer (score 0):

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
    cors: { origin : "*"}
});
```