# CORS issue while connecting client and server that run on different post

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors

I have made a Chatting app. I am running it on CodeSandBox. Now, the client AND the server are both in the same sand box, and it works. When you send a message, it broadcasts it to other users. But what I want is to make a HTML file locally. So, there will be chat.html NOT IN CODESANDBOX, on my computer. The chat.html will connect to the CodeSandbox server, and the chatapp should work. But it seems like there is a CORS error.

I tried using this: [CORS issue with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182508/cors-issue-with-socket-io). It did not work. I think the main problem is that the client and the server are not on the same port. When I try to specify the port, I can't specify it like localhost with the port. If you don't get what I mean,

I can do this with localhost

`const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');`

but I cannot do the :3000 thing with other links!
it won't work.

`const socket = io('https://DONT SEE MY URL-3000.csb.app:3000');`

Error Messages:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘the codesandbox url’ from origin ‘null’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.`

and

`GET ‘URL’ net::ERR_FAILED 302 (Found)`

I have attached my code below. Please put the server.js in a codesandbox server, and index.html locally in a notepad file, (or whatever editor you use)

server.js (run on codesandbox)

```
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("node:http");
const { join } = require("node:path");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("[Server] User Connected");
  
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server running at http://localhost:3000");
});
```

index.html (run locally):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
<!--Import Boostrap-->
    <title>ChatApp</title>
    <!--Set the title to "ChatApp"-->
    
    <!--Style all of the elements based on there ids.-->
</head>

<body>

    <p> this is just a example. when you open this webpage it should ssay "user conected" in the console of the server </p>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <!--Import socket.io, the framework for making the messages get sent between clients.-->
    <script>
        const socket = io('my codesandbox link');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

(this is not a full code just a mini example. please replicate my code in codesandbox and locally. I would have put a codesandbox link but i dont think im supposed to do that here idk.)

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain it in a simple, propably not 100% accurate way to make it easy to follow:

CORS errors happen in your users browser for security reasons when accessing content on the internet. It is not an issue within your application per se, but in the architecture. You are not meant to fix it within your application, but in your server that provides the applications-content.
I.e. you implemented some html and javascript for your websites-content, that is your application. That is fine. Your content is served with a server for example apache2, nginx, nodejs or whatever you decided to use.

In that serving instance you define the url or hostname from where you access your application AND you have to allow cross-origin access from all known-hostnames of servers you intend to use and partially get data from on the user side. Your serving instance has probaly just defined it's own url and it doesn't tells the users browser on the first visit that additional sources exist where content can be loaded from.

i.e. you need to specify from where data should be allowed to be combined on the first server your user visits. The first url server has to specify which additional servers are good to trust, otherwise it looks suspicious to the browser and it will crash.

There are a few things you can do to circumvent this:

- disable https or cors checks (NOT recommended!!!)
- allow all your additional server locations in your serving instance, this needs some `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in your servers
- don't merge the data from different locations on the user-side inside the browser, but build a single backend-applications that handles and processes the data from and to all your users

Comment: Do you know how to disable HTTP or add the headers?

Comment: yeah, but the client is not a "website" its a local file. like file://-your file-

Comment: The client side is the browser

Comment: yes, if i specify the origin, i cannot specify "file://file.html" cuz its not available publicly. i can allow all origins, but for some reason that doesn't work

Comment: when you access it with a browser through file:// you can't fuse multiple files cross origin. that won't work. you need to change your architecture, install yourself a server program like nginx which serves your file(s) and work from there on

Comment: or look into programming a seperated backend API and remove the cross origin implementation with sockets all together. but you need to run the API in a way that  both browsers can access it